# On double click get the id

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have many divs around page all with different ids and some with same classes.
How can I say on double click anywhere on the page I need to get id or class or anything from element where I double clicked?

Like when I Say:

```
$('div').dblclick(function(){

var x = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Can I say something like

```
$('body').dblclick(function(){

    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    });
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the event target, which is the element that the event was triggered on, and then get the closest DIV to that

```
$('body').dblclick(function(e){
    var x = $(e.target).closest('div').attr('id');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/goawwtau/)

Comment: I don't need closest div I made website like desktop with start and icons...
I want to use dbl click anywhere like on your own desktop and if you open folder to open folder look with files inside and if you open like web browser icon to open like webbrowser with iframe bla bla and to use it. Also if you click on empty place to nothing happen. I want on dbl click anywhere to get id of where I clicked.

Comment: "closest" just means that if you click a child element, for instance a span with text inside the DIV, it still finds the DIV even if the click originated on the span etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider registering a click event for anywhere on the `<body>` element and looking at the target to see what exactly was clicked :

```
$('body').dlbclick(function(e) {
    // You can adjust this to suit your needs
    var x = $(e.target).attr('id');
});
```

Or if you explicitly needed to target a `<div>` element relative to that, you could find the closest one and use its ID :

```
$('body').dlbclick(function(e) {
    // You can adjust this to suit your needs
    var x = $(e.target).closest('div').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: I will try this I think it is the one I need.

Answer (score 0):

Dblclick [event bubbles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/dblclick) so you can [use event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('body').on("dblclick","div",function(){
    var x = $(this).attr('id');
});
```